# How can I count categorical columns by month in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, time-series

I have time series data with a column which can take a value A, B, or C.

An example of my data looks like this:

```
date,category
2017-01-01,A
2017-01-15,B
2017-01-20,A
2017-02-02,C
2017-02-03,A
2017-02-05,C
2017-02-08,C
```

I want to group my data by month and store both the sum of the count of A and the count of B in column `a_or_b_count` and the count of `C` in `c_count`.

I've tried several things, but the closest I've been able to do is to preprocess the data with the following function:

```
def preprocess(df):
    # Remove everything more granular than day by splitting the stringified version of the date.
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].apply(lambda t: t.replace('\ufeff', '')), format="%Y-%m-%d")
    # Set the time column as the index and drop redundant time column now that time is indexed. Do this op in-place.
    df = df.set_index(df.date)
    df.drop('date', inplace=True, axis=1)
    # Group all events by (year, month) and count category by values.
    counted_events = df.groupby([(df.index.year), (df.index.month)], as_index=True).category.value_counts()
    counted_events.index.names = ["year", "month", "category"]
    return counted_events
```

which gives me the following:

```
year  month  category
2017  1      A           2
             B           1
      2      C           3
             A           1
```

The process to sum up all A's and B's would be quite manual since category becomes a part of the index in this case.

I'm an absolute pandas menace, so I'm likely making this much harder than it actually is. Can anyone give tips for how to achieve this grouping in pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this so posting though I like @Scott Boston's solution better as I combined A and B values earlier.

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format = '%Y-%m-%d')
df.loc[(df.category == 'A')|(df.category == 'B'), 'category'] = 'AB'

new_df = df.groupby([df.date.dt.year,df.date.dt.month]).category.value_counts().unstack().fillna(0)
new_df.columns = ['a_or_b_count', 'c_count']
new_df.index.names = ['Year', 'Month']

                a_or_b_count    c_count
Year    Month       
2017    1       3.0             0.0
        2       1.0             3.0
```

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: I like this solution better than mine.